# what is the return statement in server side for Kendo UI uploader

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI upload for uploading single/multiple files.
I have implemented it like,

```
 <input name="file" id="files" type="file" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#files").kendoUpload({
                async: {
                    saveUrl: "/NewFile/upload",
                    autoUpload: false,
                },

            });
      });
</script>
```

In the controller,I gave like,

```
public ActionResult upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
 {
       //Code for saving in DB
       return???
 }
```

I am able to save record in database,but It is displaying like,"Retry" and showing not successfully uploaded.so Can you tell me what is the return statement I have to use to display proper status upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller,I gave like

```
public ActionResult upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
 {
        var s = new { st = "successfully uploaded" };
       //Code for save in DB
       return json(s,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return empty response:

```
   public ActionResult upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
   {
       // Code to save in DB

       // Return an empty string to signify success
       return Content("");
   }
```

Comment: Well...and what do you do when you want to send back a validation error to the user?

Comment: Check here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/upload/metadata#receiving-metadata-from-the-save-handler